# Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: )

Tags: mysql, laravel, whmcs

I'm trying to copy a row from a table to another table with Laravel Query and I get the following error.

```
$invoice = Capsule::table('tblinvoices')->where('id', $invoiceid)->get(); //array
$copiedInvoiceid = Capsule::table('mod_myinvoices')->insertGetId(array($invoice));
```

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: )

I've used `CREATE TABLE mod_myinvoices LIKE tblinvoices` to create `mod_myinvoices` table.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: show code insertGetId()

Comment: @buildok https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts

Comment: But $invoice this is an indexed array, like ['0' => Capsule_row_1, ..]. You need to get an associative array like [column_name => value,..]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it! 
**Change**

```
    $invoice = Capsule::table('invoices')->where('id', $invoiceid)->get(); 
    $copiedInvoiceid = Capsule::table('myinvoices')->insertGetId(array($invoice));
```

**To**

```
    $invoice = Capsule::table('invoices')->where('id', $invoiceid)->first(); 
    $copiedInvoiceid = Capsule::table('myinvoices')->insertGetId((array)$invoice);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: @JohnPriestakos. Do you need more explanation. I'll update

Comment: No i got it. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
$invoice = Capsule::table('invoices')->where('id', $invoiceid)->get();

$invoiceArr = (array) $invoice[0]; // convert object to array    

$copiedInvoiceid = Capsule::table('myinvoices')->insertGetId($invoiceArr);
```